# 'Nullable object must have a value.' for List in LINQ c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

In database I have next model `tblWorkItem` with next field:

```
public List<xWorkItemItemFailReason> WorkItemItemFailReasons { get; set; }
```

When I am trying to get `tblWorkItem` data from database

```
_db.tblWorkItem.Where(x=>x.WorkItemItemFailReasons != null)
```

I have next error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'

How I can check if this field is not null?

Comment: Try this `_db.tblWorkItem.Where(x=>x.WorkItemItemFailReasons.Count() != 0)`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov still have the same error

Comment: This is Field specific error.check which field comes not nullable and make as nullable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in `xWorkItemItemFailReason` class. It has some property of primitive type (`int`, `long`, ...) that is not nullable, but has no value in database table.
Check them.

Comment: A little bit counterintuitive exception message

Answer (score 0):

In your modal class have some not nullable field so when fetching from database it comes with null values. so make it nullable .`public int? FieldName {Get;set;}`

Answer (score 0):

if its .net core 3.0 or earlier there is a known issue where

Simple query filter breaks simple projection
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13517

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure there are no data integrity problems with your foreign key relationships.  A foreign key value in the parent table that doesn't exist in the child table will throw this exception too (e.g., you set the foreign key to 0 instead of null if there's no child, and no child record in the database has a key value of 0).